# Make use of one handler for two activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

I have 2 activities in my app, say `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo` and a third class that does some work in the background say `WorkerClass`. The `WorkerClass` sends `Message`'s to the UI thread using a `Handler`.

`ActivityOne` is interested in some messages and `ActivityTwo` is interested in others, yet both of them run on the main thread. Is it possible to define one `Handler` instance that will satisfy both activities on the main thread?

So far I am thinking to create two `Handler` instances, one for `ActivityOne` and another for `ActivityTwo`. The `WorkerClass` would send messages to each activity through those 2 handler instances.

In code that would be:

```
class ActivityOne extends Activity{
 Handler mHandler = new Handler( (message) -> makeChangesToLocalActivity(message) )
}


class ActivityTwo extends Activity{
         Handler mHandler = new Handler( (message) -> makeChangesToLocalActivity(message) )
}

class WorkerClass{
 // Each activity will pass its local handler when using the WorkerClass
 Handler mActivityOneHandler,mActivityTwoHandler;
}
```

Is it ok if `WorkerClass` contains two different handlers that are both attached to the same (UI) thread? It doesn't look good but it was all I could think of.

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for a local broadcast receiver.

Comment: don't make superfluous edits just to bump your question to the first page

Comment: I thought that was ok to do